# How to display items inside listbox in dinamically created tab item

Tags: c#, xaml

I have data stored in IGroupping field of my repository class. I want to create tab item for each group of this collection, showing it`s items in listbox.

This is my code for creating tab items:

```
       foreach (var group in repository.Products)
            {   
                var tab = new MyTabItem();
                tab.Header = group.Key;
                tab.Products = group.AsEnumerable().ToList();
                tab.FontSize = 16;
                TabControlProducts.Items.Add(tab);
            }
            TabControlProducts.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Here`s part of my xaml file:

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TabControlProducts">
                    <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ListBox FontSize="16" ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MyTabItem}}, Path=Products}" Visibility="Visible">
                                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.MainGroup}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.MainForm}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.SubForm}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.Finishing}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.MaterialGroup}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.MaterialSort}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.Attest}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.Sizing}"></TextBlock>
                                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Code.SubSizing}"></TextBlock>
                                        </StackPanel>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            </ListBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
                </TabControl>
```

And declaration of MyTabItem class:

```
public class MyTabItem : TabItem
{
    public List<Product> Products;
}
```

Now I have listboxes displayed in each of tab items, but they are empty

Comment: Try making products a property rather than a field

Comment: That didn`t help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably easier to bind directly to your product class and let the TabControl wrap each one in a TabItem.

```
        foreach (var group in repository.Products)
        {
            TabControlProducts.Items.Add(group);
        }

        TabControlProducts.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Then the xaml

```
    <TabControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="TabControlProducts">
        <TabControl.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Key}"/>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>
        <TabControl.ContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ListBox FontSize="16" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Visibility="Visible">
                    itemtemplate here...
                </ListBox>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TabControl.ContentTemplate>
    </TabControl>
```

Comment: Thank you! It worked, now i have listboxes filled with items, but you could you help find the way to access and change them? Or is creating new TabControl the only solution?

Comment: @amamedov it depends on what you mean by accessing and changing them

Comment: I have other controls that filter items in listboxes